# Reduce function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have searched for previously answered questions but I think this is an exclusive challenge(pardon my English).

I have this function below that expect returns from a call back reduce function

```
const { getTrips } = require('api');
const { getDriver } = require('api')
const { getVehicle } = require('api')

/**
 * This function should return the data for drivers in the specified format
 *
 * Question 4
 *
 * @returns {any} Driver report data
 */

let trips = await getTrips().then(data => {
  return data.filter(item => item.billedAmount = parseFloat(item.billedAmount.toString().replace(',', '')), 10)
})
async function driverReport() {
  // Your code goes here
  let getId = trips.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
    acc[cur.driverID] ? acc[cur.driverID] = acc[cur.driverID] + 1 : acc[cur.driverID] = 1
    return acc
  }, {})

  let mapId = Object.keys(getId)
  // console.log(mapId)
  let result = await mapId.reduce(getReport, {})
  console.log(result)//undefined


}
```

The callback function is as below

```
async function getReport(acc, cur){


  acc = await acc
  // console.log(acc)

  let singleTrip = trips.filter(item => item.driverID == cur)
  // console.log(singleTrip)
  if(singleTrip){

    return getDriver(cur).then( async data => {
      let { name, phone, vehicleID } = data
      acc['fullName'] = name
      acc['id'] = cur
      acc['phone'] = phone
      acc['noOfTrips'] = singleTrip.length
      acc['noOfVehicle'] = vehicleID.length

      return acc

    }).catch(err =>{
      if(err){        
        console.log ('wait')
      }
    })
  }

  return acc
}
```

The call back function works properly but not returning value to the result variable above.

I have checked thoroughly and confirmed that I have use `return` appropriately but am sure am getting it wrong somewhere.
Please kindly help figure out where am getting it wrong as I am trying to get the hang of using async and await in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured that I have to return `acc` inside the reducer function. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `filter` for `trips` since it is mutating the item in place and filtering based on the `item.billedAmount` boolean value. So, if the `item.billedAmount` is `0` at any point, the item will be removed from `trips`; 
You must use `map` instead if you want to modify the value of the items. return the entire `item` after mutating rather than updating the value inside the object and getting the mutation as the value back

```
let trips = await getTrips().then(data => {
  return data.map(item => {
    item.billedAmount = parseFloat(item.billedAmount.toString().replace(',', ''));
    return item;
   })
 });
```

**Edit**
As for the question, try this ?

```
async function getReport(acc, cur){  
  let singleTrip = trips.filter(item => item.driverID == cur)
  if(singleTrip && singleTrip.length) { //filter returns empty array
    try{
     data = await getDriver(cur);
     let { name, phone, vehicleID } = data;
     acc {
       fullName: name,
       id: cur,
       phone,
       noOfTrips: singleTrip.length,
       noOfVehicle: vehicleID.length
     }
    }catch(e) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  return acc
}
```

Comment: trips is not empty as ```filter``` return the expected array . ```map``` on the other hands returns only the ```values``` of the ```item.billedAmount``` that I manipulated.

Comment: The code above in the answer should return the entire item

Comment: you should not use filter, since it is actually returning a side effect. think of it like this, each item is mutated by the function inside the filter and as long as the item.billedAmount is not `0`, it would return a non-zero value to the filter, thus keeping the item inside the array. but it is logically incorrect and can cause wrong values in runtime too when the parseFloat() returns zero. Use map like above and do not map `item => item.billedAmount = ...` directly

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just did that but still the same as in the image below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZWxk.png)

Comment: I just tried the second suggestion and still not working. I need to catch errors from the getDriver promise function so I used the code like this ```   if (singleTrip && singleTrip.length){

    return getDriver(cur).then( async data => {
      let { name, phone, vehicleID } = data
      acc = {
        fullName: name,
        id: cur,
        phone,
        noOfTrips: singleTrip.length,
        noOfVehicle: vehicleID.length
      }
      
      return acc

    }).catch(err =>{
    })
  }

  return acc
}```

Comment: if you need to catch with async await, you must use try catch

Comment: yes I did that but the challenge am having now is exporting the function. It says driverReport is not a function in the other file.

Comment: share your code as a stackblitz or a sandbox or a jsfiddle